# Testing data returned by axios updates the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tdd, axios, jestjs

I'm attempting to TDD a React component that will make a few API calls, but I'm struggling with how to test that responses affect the DOM as expected. In this example I'm making a request to get a list of posts, updating the state which then updates the DOM to show said list.

This works in reality, but my test fails because it can't find the `li` element I'm looking for (it finds `0`, rather than `1`), despite me being able to see the element in the error output.

Where am I going wrong? Feel free to rip my test setup to shreds, I'm just getting to grips with TDDing React components.

```
// PostList.js

import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class PostList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      posts: []
    };

    this.getPosts = this.getPosts.bind(this);
  }

  async getPosts() {
    return axios.get("/api/posts/").then(response => {
      return response.data.posts;
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPosts().then(posts => {
      this.setState({
        posts: posts
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const posts = this.state.posts.map(post => (
      <li key={post.id}>
        <strong>{post.title}</strong> {post.description}
      </li>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Posts:</h1>
        <ul>{posts}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PostList;
```

```
// PostList.test.js

import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import axios from "axios";
import MockAdapter from "axios-mock-adapter";

import PostList from "./PostList";

describe("<PostList />", () => {
  let shallowPostList;
  let posts = [{ id: 1, title: "Hello", description: "World" }];

  const getPostsMock = new MockAdapter(axios);

  const PostList = () => {
    if (!shallowPostList) {
      shallowPostList = shallow(<PostList />);
    }

    return shallowPostList;
  };

  getPostsMock
    .onGet("/api/posts/")
    .reply(200, { posts });

  beforeEach(() => {
    shallowPostList = undefined;
  });

  describe("render()", () => {
    it("renders one post item when one post exists", done => {
      const PostListItems = PostList().find("li");

      setTimeout(() => {
        expect(PostListItems).toHaveLength(1);
        done();
      }, 1);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think whether it's TDD or not isn't an essential detail. I'm also a bit confused about your approach.

The solution depends on your testing framework as well. The most popular one for React is Jest, therefore I can come up with a solution that works with that pretty well.

If I were you, I'd separate the async function into an individual file, thus it eases the mocking.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const getPosts = async () => axios.get('/api/posts/');

export default getPosts;
```

Let's suppose that you have a *PostList* component within the usual *src* folder along with the *index.js* file.

```
.
├── src
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── PostList
│       ├── __mocks__
│          ├── GetPosts.js
│       ├── PostList.js
│       ├── PostList.test.js
│       ├── GetPosts.js
```

The *__mocks__* folder is recognized by Jest and works as expected, so long as the file naming convention is being followed:

- the file name should be the same as the one that is being mocked.

Also pay attention to use `jest.mock('...')` in the test file.

Based on your mock example, you can define something similar to this in *__mocks__/GetPosts.js*.

```
const returnedData = [{
   id: 1,
   title: "Hello",
   description: "World"
}];

const getPosts = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(() => returnedData);

export default getPosts;
```

```
// PostList.js 
...
async componentDidMount() {
   const posts = await GetPosts();
   this.setState({
      posts,
   });
}
...
```

And your test file should be something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import PostList from './PostList.js';

jest.mock('./GetPosts.js'); // Here you "tell" to Jest to mock the function.

describe('<PostList />', () => {
   let wrapper;

   beforeAll(async () => {
      wrapper = await shallow(<PostList />);
   });

   describe('componentDidMount', () => {
      it('renders an li tag', () => {
         expect(wrapper.find('li')).toHaveLength(1);
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much - that is much nicer (and works!). I'd love to find out what confused you about my approach so I could explain how I got there, if only SO allowed users to message each other...